# Balance does not increase by mining in private net

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I can not mining from geth(v1.8.3) by using private_net.
But I can not increase my account balance.
I want to increase my account balance.

Is there anyone to solve it?

My execution commands are below.

after executing this command, I confirmed mining start.

`$ geth --datadir ~/private_net --port 7545 --networkid 1111  console 2>>node.log`

`$ eth.miner()`

but balance does not increase.

`$ eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])`

### genesis.json

```
{
  "config": {
        "chainId": 10,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
  "alloc"      : {},
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x20000",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to run the miner is:

```
miner.start()
```

You can even specify the number of CPU threads with:

```
miner.start(7)
```

And stop it again with:

```
miner.stop()
```

However, for private chains I would recommend you [proof-of-authority](https://wiki.parity.io/Demo-PoA-tutorial) chains or [instant-seal](https://wiki.parity.io/Private-development-chain) chains such as Parity provides. This allows you not to spend too much energy on sealing blocks.

*Note, I work for Parity.*